# Does anyone know what kind of rod to use with these brackets?

Tags: brackets

We have an old home (circa 1920).  Our front door has windows on the side and above those windows are these curtain brackets.  Unfortunately the remodelers didn't leave the curtain rods, and they are unfamiliar to me.

Can anyone tell me what the name is or what kind of rod goes with them?

[image: close-up]
[image: both brackets]

Sorry for the poor-quality image.

Comment: It looks like those get a non-bent version of a standard expandable rod. I had some in my house that I threw away 2 years ago. Sorry I didn't save them.

Comment: Take another picture at night, it will help with the glare.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar shaped curtain brackets. They used a length of coiled spring rather than a solid rod.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

These brackets are to stretch something - a string or something similiar - to hang curtain onto. These are definately not rod-bearing brackets.

Comment: I think those shaped cutouts are to provide tension, not to wrap or stretch anything. They accept and oval rod

Answer (score 0):

I had these same brackets original to my house (before a rather slash and burn approach to cleaning and cosmetic updates). They can receive one of several types of rods. There is a cutout portion that acts to tension the oval shaped rod that goes between both sides. It is doubtful you will find an exact, original replacement. I suspect mind had been long lost to time and a clumsy hand.

The profile of an expandable, oval profile, curtain rode could work if you delicately cut off the curved necks (scroll saw or similar).

Similarly, it wouldn't look to out of place to whittle down a dowel rod, so that the ends were shaped and tapered to fit snugly into the brackets.